# Hash function with good performance on extremely short messages

Tags: universal-hash

Are there randomized almost universal hashes that are fast for extremely short messages (usually <10 bytes)?

Edit: This is for hash tables, so it only needs to be hard enough to break to make the HashDOS attack not worthwhile.  I am specifically looking for a solution for LuaJIT.  Since Lua interns all strings, this needs to be *really fast*.  SipHash-1-3 is too slow.

Comment: Keccak[400] with a bit rate of 240, a capacity of 160 and 12 round ? See [here](http://keccak.noekeon.org/crunchy_contest.html) for the collision contest.

Comment: @Biv how fast is that? Keccak is not exactly known for being fast in software and I need <1cycle/byte on tiny messages.  It is okay to use a stronger algorithm for longer messages.

Comment: CLHash: https://github.com/lemire/clhash

Comment: Are you looking for a PRF, or for a UHF?  Very different beasts.  I suspect you're looking for a PRF, not a UHF, because I suspect that for LuaJIT's string table you can't generally assume that the adversary is nonadaptive.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I am looking for a PRF.

Comment: @Demi Then I'm afraid you might need to hire a professional cryptographer to invent a novel primitive, if SipHash is too costly!  Another alternative is to use a hash table of, say, compressed radix trees, with a very fast but not pseudorandom hash function: under nonadversarial input, the hash table gives high expected performance; under adversarial input, the compressed radix trees give reasonable worst-case performance.